# Suggestion for searching content in MongoDB in MVC Ajax application

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Our database stores photo albums and photos. 
Each album has title, tags, description.
Each photo has title, tags and description.

All I want is the ability to show 5 search results as soon as the user types a word in a search box.

Then show 50 search result per page and so on.

1. Which fields should I index - only title or tags (ar embedded array) or both?
2. What to use for best search experience - MongoDB index on filed or other type of index?
   Solution must scale as the data grows.

If anyone can help me with some pointers on how to proceed, that will be great.

I am still using older version of MongoDB 1.8

Thanks

Comment: You should index the fields you're searching. If you're doing a keyword search, take a look at this: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-data-for-keyword-search/. But, if you're looking for a full text search solution, until 10gen releases the `text` search feature designed for production, I'd suggest you might look at Solr or ElasticSearch.

Comment: And, also, upgrade to 2.4+. :)  There are a lot of new features and performance enhancements since 1.8.

Comment: Hey WiredPrairie, If 10gen releases text search, then would that replace Lucene\Solr? In that case not enough ROI in looking for Lucene\Solr search solution as it will be temporary. What is the recommended by Mongodb as search solution for large conrent in production for text search?

Comment: There's no timetable for the full-text search being production ready that I know of. MongoDB releases with even version numbers are production ready, except the text stuff isn't -- it's a preview. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-text-search/. 2.5 is next (and that's a development version). My prediction: If you need full-text search sooner than 9-12 months, look at other options (and even then, you're taking a risk on the MongoDB solution). It still may not be as good as the ES/Solr options.

Comment: Hey WiredPrairie, Do you have some pointers on how to set up Lucene\Solr in MongoDB? I need to search just the title field. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean, setup Solr in MongoDB? You'll need to send docs to Solr to be indexed.

Answer (score 0):

If you require only the title to be searchable as per your last comment, then you could simply use the $regex operator:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/regex/#op._S_regex

If you anchor the regular expression (i.e. /^something/) then it will even use your indexes which will be super fast.

The performance of this on a huge database is not going to be fantastic though.

Otherwise, as WiredPrairie suggests, look into the keyword search:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-data-for-keyword-search/